# Doubles will not output in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that I want to fill with values that are Doubles. The DataGridView filled fine when the values were strings, but now it outputs `System.Double[]` in the first column and nothing in any other column. I know the conversion is working because I can print the double values to the console. How do I format all columns programmatically? (I don't want to use the designer)

My code:

```
Dim cols() as String = {"col1", "col2", "col3"} ' this goes on for 33 cols
Dim currentRow As String()
Dim row() As Double
Dim c As Integer

DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "G"
DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 33

For c = 0 To (cols.Length - 1)
     DataGridView1.Columns(c).Name = cols(c)
Next
While Not at EndOfFile ' This line and the next are semi-pseudocode, but it's the same idea
    read/parse line into currentRow
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 0 To (currentRow.Length - 1)
        ReDim Preserve row(x)
        Double.TryParse(currentRow(x), row(x))
    Next

    With Me.DataGridView1.Rows
        .Add(row)
    End With
```

Screenshot of the output:

[image: Screenshot of the output]

Comment: You are adding an *array* of doubles to each row.  Just set it as the datasource

Comment: @Plutonix I forgot to add that I'm looping through lines in a file, and adding a row in the DataGrid for each line. I've edited my code above to reflect that

Comment: `Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row(0), row(1), row(2))`

Comment: That works, but I'd rather not hard-code each item in the 33 columns of the row. Looping through the row outside the add function adds each in the first column. Is there a way I can loop through the row to add each value?

Comment: `Dim i as integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Add | For x As Integer = 0 to row.Count - 1 | DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(x).Value = row(x) | Next`

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks, that works. If you put it in an answer I will mark it as solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first add the row to the grid, then loop through your array to add the information to each cell.

```
Dim i as integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Add
For x As Integer = 0 to row.Count - 1
  DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(x).Value = row(x)
Next
```